# Can I really have just one column in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

From the docs:

> A table view in the UIKit framework is limited to a single column because it is designed for a device with a small screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have look in the developer docuementation [A Closer Look at Table-View Cells](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) how to setup multiple columns in a table view cell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes... unless you add subview in cell that looks like more than one column... 
i.e 2 label in each cell with same size and horizontally aliened can look like Table with 2 column...

Answer (score 1):

What about putting another tableview next to that one and synchronize the movement (scrolling)? :)